# Slight change of double value in C++

Tags: c++

The value of d which is a double when compared to 0.01 is not satisfied due to presence of some digits at the end of the number which I found using flags . Why does this occur and how do we overcome this ? Thank you .
Code for this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/06I81.png

Comment: Please don't post code-images. Post your actual code and output here.

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf)

Comment: Please read about IEEE floating point representations. `0.1` is not exactly representable as a floating point number in binary representation. A long version is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), a shorter one [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ( abs( d - 0.01 ) < 0.0000001 ) ...`

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from a bit more expansion.